# Drop action does not work for UITableView on Mac M1 (Designed for iPad)

Tags: swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop, apple-m1

We have implemented sorting of cells in a table. Everything seems simple:

Added

```
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.isEditing = true
```

Implemented

```
// UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(_: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    ...
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return ...
}

func tableView(_: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    true
}

func tableView(_: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    true
}

func tableView(_: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    ...
}
```

And

```
// UITableViewDelegate

func tableView(_: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt _: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func tableView(_: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt _: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .none
}
```

Everything works great on iPhone and iPad.
But it doesn't work on Mac M1. That is, the cell can be dragged, but it is not inserted anywhere. And when you let go, it returns to its original place.

Then we implemented the delegates **UITableViewDragDelegate** and **UITableViewDropDelegate**

```
// UITableViewDragDelegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    return ...
}

// UITableViewDropDelegate

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    ...
}
```

And added

```
tableView.dragDelegate = self
tableView.dropDelegate = self
tableView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
```

As a result, UITableViewDragDelegate handles the drag action, but UITableViewDropDelegate does not react in any way. It turns out that we are dragging the cell, but it is not clear where.

Does anyone know why Drop Action doesn't work on the Mac M1?